# VB, .Net non-blocking TcpClient

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have working example of TCP listener which receives data on particular PORT and if needed sends response. The problem is that when script sends response whole process is waiting and doesn't accept new connections. Maybe someone can help to improve code so it start accepting new connections without blocking?

```
Public Shared Sub test()
        Dim listener As TcpListener = Nothing
        Dim port As Integer = 555

        Try
            listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port)
            listener.Start()

            'Buffer for reading data
            Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
            Dim data As String = Nothing

            ' Enter the listening loop.
            While True
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ")
                ' Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                ' You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                Dim client As TcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient()
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!")

                data = Nothing

                ' Get a stream object for reading and writing
                Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

                ' Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                Dim i As Integer = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

                While (i <> 0)

                    ' Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data)

                    If data.Contains("ppp") Then
                        Console.WriteLine("Contains ppp")
                        ' Send back a response.
                        Response(stream, "my_response")
                    End If

                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
                End While
                ' Shutdown and end connection
                Console.WriteLine("connection closed")
            End While
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(e)
        Finally

            If listener IsNot Nothing Then
                listener.Stop()
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Response(stream As Object, message As String)
        Dim response As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
        stream.Write(response, 0, response.Length)
        Console.WriteLine("response {0} sent", message)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you committed to using `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`?  Would you consider using `Socket` instead?

Comment: You need to break this down in to parts that all run on different threads. Async\Await is the easiest way to get in to modern multi-threading: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/easy-async-and-await-for-vbs-part-1-or/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: Nope, I am not committed to use TcpListener and TcpClient, it was just a bit easier to understand how to work with these classes.

Comment: I know, it is too much, but maybe someone can help rewrite my example using Async\Await?

Comment: Maybe someone can help to modify code so it asynchronously receive data, send response and close connection when it is no longer needed? I tried to put whole NetworkStream to new thread, but probably it should work in a bit different way.